# WordPress - cannot use YouTube videos as attached media

Tags: wordpress

I tried using 2 different plugins for this purpose([ombed](https://github.com/wp-plugins/oembed-in-library), [this old plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/add-youtube-video-to-media-library/))

The problem is, that on the post page, the URL to YouTube is displayed, but inside an IMG tag, instead of an embed \ iframe .

E.G:

```
<img src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1SO_tuALYgQ&amp;feature=youtu.be" alt="" class="cover">
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- To quickly embed a **YouTube video**, simply copy the video’s URL
  from your web browser’s address bar while viewing the video.
- Paste it on a line by itself in your **post/page** editor

  **WordPress will take care of the rest!**

[See detailed description here](http://en.support.wordpress.com/videos/youtube/)